# How can I set the layout_height on an TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I was wondering if it was possible to set, in the xml, the `layout_height` parameter to few dp more than the `wrap_content` value ?

For example `wrap_content` + 10 dp

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Why you want such  wrap_content + 10 dp?? If u want spacing, u can use margin or paddinig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create extra space inside TextView with padding.

You can create extra space outside TextView with margin.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm always confusing them :)

Answer (score 4):

Do one thing, try padding  :

use `padding` for that.

you can add these in your TextView . It will add 5 dp space in  left, top, right and bottom.

```
android:padding="5dp"
```

But if you want to add only top and bottom space then add:

```
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using padding top attribute.
set the text view height to "wrap_content"
set padding attribute as android:paddingTop="10dp"
also set gravity as central_vertical, to align the text central_vertical inside the text view.